# Track node js module installation time

Tags: node.js, time, module, installation

How to find my node module installation time over a period time? Assume I make changes and release every week.

If there is way to find out increase in installation time of my module it would help me to narrow down to figure out the fix causing the issue. Any thoughts!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/slow-deps could be useful